# Why does JHipster not generating a DTO object for each domain?

Tags: jhipster

I'm a little curious.

Why does JHipster not generating a DTO object for each domain object and sending the domain objects directly to the UI layer ?

-talx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DTO generation is configured on a per-entity basis, with the `"dto": "mapstruct"` option in your entity JSONs.

For a guide on how to use DTOs and an explanation for why they aren't enabled for every entity by default, check the official docs here: http://jhipster.github.io/using-dtos/

Answer (score 2):

DTO generation can be enabled in the `entities.jdl` file by adding

```
dto * with mapstruct
service * with serviceClass
```

Then generate the code with `jhipster import-jdl ./entities.jdl`

For more information see here https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#optiondeclaration